# **what versions of python does HTMltestrunner support**

Tags: python, selenium

**Problem:**

I am trying to use `HTMltestrunner` to generate HTML report for selenium tests. But it is giving me Import Module error. This is the error message I am receiving

> ImportError: No module named HTMLTestRunner

**Question:**

What versions of Python does `HTMltestrunner` support?

Comment: Which version of HTMltestrunner  do you have?

Comment: I am using HTMLtestrunner version 1.1.2.

Comment: how to check the version of HTMLTestRunner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it provided [here](https://github.com/dash0002/HTMLTestRunner) `HTMltestrunner` is supporting Python 3 - 3.5. Also there are some test samples, which you can use. Hope this helps.